# How to Refresh ExpandableList Without Setting Custom Adapter All Over Again

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, expandablelistview, baseadapter

I have a custom adapter which extends `BaseExpandableListAdapter`. That adapter uses LinkedHashMap>  variable type as source. When a new data comes, i call .setAdapter method to refresh expandable list which is very unefficient and bad coding. When i update that linkedhashmap and call notifydatasetchanged and notifydatasetinvalidated nothing occurs. here is my filling code;

**NOTE: in my adapter hasStableIds is true**

```
 LinkedHashMap<String,ArrayList<Income>> IncomeList = new LinkedHashMap<>();
SetIncomeTask incomeTask;
IncomesAdapter incomesAdapter;
IncomeDbAdapter incomeDbAdapter;

....

 class SetIncomeTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        incomeDbAdapter = new IncomeDbAdapter(getActivity());
        if(incomeDbAdapter.selectAllCount()>0){
            if(groupBy.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0)
                IncomeList.putAll(incomeDbAdapter.selectLastEntriesFilterByDate(DefaultValues.lastDays));
            else
                IncomeList.putAll(incomeDbAdapter.selectLastEntriesFilterByCategory(DefaultValues.lastDays));
                return null;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {

        if(IncomeList != null) {
            if(incomes.getAdapter()== null) {
                if(groupBy.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0)
                    incomesAdapter = new IncomesAdapter(getActivity(), IncomeList,true);
                else
                    incomesAdapter = new IncomesAdapter(getActivity(), IncomeList,false);

                incomes.setAdapter(incomesAdapter);
            }else {
                incomesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                incomesAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default make your adapter `null`, by this whenever you call `AsyncTask` it will take adapter as `null`.

Thank you if i helped you.

Comment: setting adapter all over again and instantiating (new Adapter) are the same, aren't they? This is  very inefficient and bad coding. This part is i wanna get rid of. Creating new adapter means; getView method will be called again and again.